# Initialization with referenced object

Tags: c++

I have a method like this:

```
MyClass& Smth::getMyClass() {
    return myClassObj;
}
```

and now these two examples work the same way (vs2012):

```
MyClass& a = smthObj.getMyClass();
a.whatever();

MyClass a = smthObj.getMyClass();
a.whatever();
```

How to interpret this?

Comment: Define "work the same way". In what way do you expect them to differ, and how does the code diverge from your expectation?

Comment: In the second case, the object will still be copied.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I meant that you can call it the same way by using '.', and the compiling will not fail.

Comment: Yes, and why would you assume anything else?

Comment: @Sebastian Redl, maybe because he is learning C++. Isn't that so obvious?

Comment: Even newcomers usually have a reason why they expect code to work in a specific way. I'm curious what that reason is here. It's pointers that have a different member access syntax, not references, and whatever book or tutorial the OP is using should have pointed that out. Moreover, I'm curious why the OP thinks that the function used to initialize `a` has anything to do with the outcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to interpret this?

```
MyClass& a = smthObj.getMyClass();
a.whatever();
```

`a` is a **reference** to`smthObj`'s data member. The second line calls `whatever()` on the data member.

```
MyClass a = smthObj.getMyClass();
a.whatever();
```

`a` is a **copy** of `smthObj`'s data member. The second line calls `whatever()` on that copy.

Comment: Doesn't the 'MyClass&' and 'MyClass' mean another type? Because of that I have assumed that the compiling should fail when using MyClass a; because the returned type is 'MyClass&'.

Comment: @tobi `MyClass` and `MyClass&` are different, but what is happening is that a `MyClass` copy is being made from a reference to another `MyClass` object (`Smth`'s data member)

Comment: Does it mean that there's an implicit cast?

Comment: @tobi no, a reference is an alias to an object. So when you say `MyClass a = smthObj.getMyClass()`, it is exactly the same as saying `MyClass a = SomeOtherMyClassObject`. You are just constructing an instance by copying another one.

Answer (score 4):

They don't work the same way. In the first case the function returns a reference and the caller binds another reference to the same object. Any operation on `a` will be applied to `myClassObj`. In the second case the caller makes a copy of the object, any operation applied to `a` will be applied to the copy and won't affect the original object.

Comment: Why do I get a copy of the object when using MyClass a = ...? I have specified in the method's signature that I want a reference to it.

Comment: You return a reference. However, you then proceed to initialize a full object. So that full object will copy the contents of the reference. (Did you perchance learn PHP before C++? Because PHP's references are insane and a bad guide.)

Comment: @SebastianRedl How is that proceeding made? Is there any implicit cast or something?

Comment: By writing `MyClass a = ...`, you specify that `a` is a full object, by lack of anything that says otherwise. To simplify what really happens, the compiler then chooses a constructor to initialize that object with; since the initializer is a call to a function that returns `MyClass&`, the copy constructor will most likely be the best match and get called.

Comment: @tobi: Another way to look at it is that the expression is evaluated by parts. When you call the function, the signature is used to determine what the result of the right hand side is. Then the construction (looks like assignment, but is really construction) is evaluated. The function says *I want a reference*, the constructor says *I want a copy of the object*. When processing the constructor call, it does not really care whether the right hand side is a value or a reference, as references are **aliases** to other objects, and after initialization they *are* the other object.